# Why is my button being removed from its superview before it completes its animation?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I am trying to move an my button to a certain part of the screen [as a custom button class GameBlock] and then remove it from its superview. However, it is acting weird in the sense that it removes itself from the superview before it completes the animation and I have no clue why. May somebody please help me out? I appreciate it.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: movementTime,               
               delay: 0.0,
               options: [],
               animations: {
                   movedBlock.center = gridCoord[hitBlock.x][hitBlock.y]
               },
               completion: nil)

if movedBlock.center == gridCoord[hitBlock.x][hitBlock.y] {
    movedBlock.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem, this should works. Your view will be removed after the animation. The `completion` closure will be called at the end of the animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: movementTime,               
               delay: 0.0,
               options: [],
               animations: {
                   movedBlock.center = gridCoord[hitBlock.x][hitBlock.y]
               },
               completion: { _ in
    if movedBlock.center == gridCoord[hitBlock.x][hitBlock.y] {
        movedBlock.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```